# App is not detected after iOS app is re-signed

Tags: ios, cordova, crashlytics

I am having a specific problem when using the Fabric/Crashlytics iOS SDK:

We have an iOS app signed with an enterprise license which wis automatically detected by Fabric as intended. But for our client we have to upload that app to a proprietary app store where it is resigned with a new App ID. After this process, the app is not detected in Fabric any more. What could be the reason for this?

We are using Fabric for a cordova project with the cordova plugin

https://github.com/sarriaroman/FabricPlugin

The iOS version uses Fabric SDK 1.6.5 and Crashlytics SDK 3.6.0 framework bundles.

I would be very thankful for any help.

Comment: Why the minus one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here.

While Cordova based apps are not officially supported, a build and a run of the app is required to activate the app within Fabric. With the resigning, if a build and run hasn't happened, the app wouldn't activate.

Comment: Thank you, maybe that is the problem. I will try to solve this with the tech staff of the proprietary app store solution.

Comment: If the app is activated, the signals should be received correctly, right? In that case, is it somehow possible to manually activate the app for a specific App ID?

Comment: @MonkeyKing once the app is activated, then data should flow over. If you email into support(at)fabric(dot)io, I can look into manually activating the app, but please provide both ids and the API keys being used.